# Raspberry Pi B (2012) doesn't boot at low temperatures (0°C - +3°C / +32°F - +38°F )

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have Raspberry Pi model B from year 2012 (2xUSB, 512RAM).
It works perfectly inside in room temperature. But when I take it outside (0°C - +3°C / +32°F - +38°F ) and my RPI is outside for ~15minutes and I try to boot it, first PWR diod is red and ACT diod is blinking as normal when it reads from SD card, but after few seconds ACT diod is green continually and my RPI doesn't finish boot sequence.
(I test only RPI without any modules/extensions. Only power and ethernet cables are connected)
When I take hair dryer to warm it up and I blow hot air for ~1 minute RPI can reboot without any problems.

I need to install it in very small case outside the building, and temperature in my place can go down to ~ -10°C in winter, so do you think that Raspberry Pi 3 or Raspberry Pi Zero works better in lower temperatures?

I read articles about booting RPI in [extreme cold liquid nitrogen](https://www.geek.com/chips/raspberry-pi-proven-to-be-stable-when-submerged-in-liquid-nitrogen-1555235/) so I don't know why my RPI is so sensitive to temperature :/

Comment: This isn't really programming-related, you should try https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-hardware/raspberry-pi-model-b/hardware-general-specifications), which might not be official, it seems that the LAN chip on the RPi is the limiting component, being only specified to operate correctly in the 0-70 Celsius range.

Depending on what you are trying to build, you might have more luck with an Arduino board, if a micro-controller is sufficient. That should endure the cold a bit better.